# Parallel and Multicore Processing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore

This is towards the extreme in R's capabilities I think, but here goes...

I'm doing some heavy processing in R in which I've written a function which does all the leg work from a single call. However, I'd like to thread or utilise more than a single core.

I've looked at the Parallel package, which comes up as deprecated. I'd ideally like to call function as a new thread.

I understand the complexities of parallel computing and that it's not the easiest thing in the world, but I'd appreciate it if anyone knew of some packages that would be useful or anything I've overlooked.

Cheers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `multicore` package is deprecated: not `parallel`.  Take a look at the documentation for the `mclapply` function: it's the easiest way to execute functions in parallel in the `parallel` package.  It's very similar to `lapply` but with a few new, optional arguments:

```
library(parallel)
myfun <- function(i) { Sys.sleep(1); i }
mclapply(1:8, myfun, mc.cores=4)
```

Note that `mclapply` uses processes, not threads, and doesn't support parallel execution on Windows.  For Windows, you should take a look at `parLapply`, which is also in `parallel`.  It is also similar to `lapply`, but requires a cluster object as the first argument.  Here's the same example, but this works on essentially any platform:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
myfun <- function(i) { Sys.sleep(1); i }
parLapply(cl, 1:8, myfun)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: But the functions like `parLapply` in the parallel package does work in parallel on windows, it just takes a little more setup to use than `mclapply`.

Comment: @GregSnow I finally understood your comment and hopefully improved my answer.  Thanks.