# R parallel: Error in unserialize(node$con) in HPC

Tags: r, multithreading, hpc

I'm running a multicore function on a HPC cluster using R:

```
library(parallel)
Myfunc(data, parameters=1:n, mc.cores=n_cores)
```

Myfunc comes from a library that supports multithread and loop through the parameters 1:n that mod(n,n_cores)=0. I get the following error:

```
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
Calls: FindTopicsNumber ... FUN -> recvData -> recvData.SOCKnode -> unserialize
Execution halted
```

I have tried the solution in previous questions [Parallel and Multicore Processing in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054026/parallel-and-multicore-processing-in-r) to use mclapply but did not work. Did I miss something to initialize multicores?

Comment: First a formal clarification: the term "thread" has a very special meaning in operating systems and the parallel processing world.  To be safe, use the term "multiprocessing" instead of "multithread[ing]" because the parallel package only does the former and very few R packages do _multithreading and when they do they do it internally using native code.

Comment: Second feedback: it's really hard to help on your attempt if all you give is: "... but did not work".

Comment: Back to the main question: From the traceback of your error it looks like you are using a PSOCK backend, that is, somewhere internally your set of background workers are set up using `workers <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)`.  Each worker will run in a separate R process.  The error message itself - `Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection` suggests that one or more of the workers have died.  This may happen if you for instance run out of memory.  Try with `n_cores = 2` or even `n_cores = 1` to see if that works.